# column reference is ambiguous , Sequelize error

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables A, B , C. Table B and C have their Ids as FK in table A. That's `bId`, `cId` . And Table C is also a FK in table B. I am trying to query, outer join the 3 and count a column `cId` in A. Below is my query.

```
 models.A.findAll({
        attributes: ['cId', sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('cId')), 'total'],
        include: [{ model: models.B, attributes: ['cId','Item']}, { model: models.C, attributes: ['ImageUrl'] } ],
        group: ['cId']
    }).then(function(collection){
        res.send(collection);
    });
```

MY query is failing and throwing the error , `column cId` is ambiguous. I think because column cId is a FK in both A and B. Please how do i achieve that ? Any help would be appreciated.

**update**

I update my query to

```
models.A.findAll({
            attributes: ['A.cId', sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('A.cId')), 'total'],
            include: [{ model: models.B, attributes: ['cId','Item']}, { model: models.C, attributes: ['ImageUrl'] } ],
            group: ['A.cId']
        }).then(function(collection){
            res.send(collection);
        });
```

The error seems to have gone . However, a different error appears saying `A.id, B.id, C.id` must appear in the group by . When i checked the query returned by sequelize, i noticed it returns A.id , B.id , C.id amng the attributes which i didn't asked it to. Please what am i missing? Where am i going wrong?

Comment: if you use ORM, you better user naming convetion when all column names accros one database have unique name.

Comment: Try using tableA.cld and tableB.cld

Comment: @Vao Tsun the table name A, B and C are not the original names. Also , can you pls share a link to an article or tut on the orm naming conventions, perhaps would have a look.?

Comment: sorry - no docs. just experience. ORM rarely uses `schema_name.table_name.column_name` names, so it is just easier to have all database columns with unique names